# How to see Azure Event Hub metrics grouped by consumer group?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azureportal

I have an Azure Event Hub topic, for which I have two consumer groups which listen. One of the consumers is struggling to retrieve data from the topic, but the other does so successfully. In order to troubleshoot the connection issues of the struggling consumer, I would like to be able to see the outbound traffic for only the consumer group in question, excluding the traffic for the other consumer group(s).

In other words, I would like to group or filter the requests, messages and throughput metrics based on consumer group. Is this possible? If so, how? I cannot find a way to do so in the Azure Portal. I can filter the consumer group list displayed under the metrics, but that has no effect on the graphed metrics.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups), Messages sent to Consumer groups are sent to partitions. You cannot specify which message to be sent to a specified Consumer group.

[image]

Event Hub itself can't do any filtering instead

- You can use a tool to look at this data and filter out what you need called [Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/stream-analytics/), which processes the data from event hub and then send it where you need. Here is an   [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/process-data-azure-stream-analytics) that you can refer to.
- You can also use a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata?view=azure-dotnet#properties)  for each message. After reading incoming messages from the consumer group, you may apply the property to decide whether to process or discard them.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Filtering Azure Event Hubs events with low latency](https://medium.com/datareply/filtering-azure-event-hubs-events-with-low-latency-8ac1c3f4214e)
2. [Azure event hubs and multiple consumer groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789320/azure-event-hubs-and-multiple-consumer-groups)
3. [Understanding Azure Event Hubs partitioned consumer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086482/understanding-azure-event-hubs-partitioned-consumer-pattern)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SwethaKandikonda-MT, but it doesn't answer the actual question of how to group/filter metrics based on consumer groups, so I cannot accept it.